# Condition for Connectedness of Graph of Prime Numbers Differing in only $1$ Digit

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

<sup>(This question is inspired by the [StackOverflow question *Converting prime numbers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653475/converting-prime-numbers) by [@Manas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158163/manas), which turns out to be the [problem `PPATH` of SPOJ](http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PPATH/).)</sup>

Let's construct a graph $G$ of all primes $p$ having $L$ digits in base-$n$. Two primes $p$ and $q$ form an edge in $G$ iff they only differ in $1$ digit (e.g. $1\mathbf{0}09$ and $1\mathbf{1}09$ form an edge).

Is there some (approximated?) condition on $n$ and $L$ that $G$ is connected?

For example, it *seems* that when $n$ is odd $G$ is usually disconnected, while when $n$ is even ($>2$) $G$ is usually connected.

Answer (score 1):

I think Terry Tao's paper might help here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3361

It shows that the isolated primes are of positive relative density.  I'm not sure if the method can be extended to show that there are large connected blocks.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems fairly advanced. You may want to consider asking it on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).